# How to update a state array multiple times faster than the setState without overwriting?

Tags: reactjs

my problem is quite simple.

I have an array which I create with useState

```
const [childFound, setChildFound] = React.useState([])
```

This array contains a boolean for each line in a table and an update is called by each child when they need to change it. However, if I change directly the entry in the array (as in childFound[1] = false), the component doesn't update because the setter wasn't called.

But, if I call setChildFound with a modified copy of childFound, the component seems to wait a bit until setting the state, and so several children call it in between. This means each of them makes a copy of the original childFound, modifies their boolean and set it. This overwrite the setChildFound of the precedent one, and only the last caller actually changes the array

Is there a workaround or am I just supposed to proceed completely differently ?

Comment: can you give some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should update it something like this

```
setChildFound( prevState => {
  let newState = [...prevState]
  newState[1] = false
  return newState
 }
)
```

This way all callers will update the state.
Reference: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates

This happens, because react optimizes state updates, so setting the state multiple times in a functin only causes one rerender. With functional update, you always have the access to the last real state value.